# Print pdf for file saved on webserver without human intervention

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a pdf file saved on development web server. I need to print the pdf stored on webserver without user interaction. below is the code I have, this works fine on localhost, But when trying to print from server where application is hosted (IIS), print does not work. Also I dont get any error. Please help if I am doing something wrong.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Verb = "PrintTo";
info.FileName = Server.MapPath("/Survey.pdf");                   
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.Arguments = "\\\\servername\\printname";
```

Comment: Does your server have the print spooler enabled?  Many servers do not

Comment: Is there a pdf reader application installed on that sever?

Comment: Yes Pdf reader is installed

Comment: Yes Print spooler is started

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and error we used spire PDF from NUget package manager to do server side printing. this is a free utility available on Nuget. Hope this helps someone with similar situation.